# Android - How to terminate application super clean

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

I have a fairly complex app which in many cases calls `post` or `postDelayed` methods on `Handler`. Everything is working fine as of now.

But, I am worried that when Android decides to pause/kill the activity I may still have some very important tasks pending to be executed. Just ignoring them will affect integrity of the data.

I am aware of `onPause` and `onDestroy` calls on `Activity` class and I am already using them for normal cleanups. But I am not sure how I should handle the pending stuff in the `Handler` object.

Am I supposed to somehow get all the pending ones from Handler and call their run method explicitly, by sitting in a loop inside the `onPause/onDestroy`?
or
Does Android has a standard way of handling this scenario?

I am deeply in need of some guidance on this subject.
Please help.

-Androbean

Comment: Probably service has more chances to finish the pending tasks. But in other hand what kind of data are you saving? If you are using sqlite then you should not worried about it if you have a good ER model design.

Comment: The data is not really big enough to put in a DB. I am saving them in some files under cache directory.

Comment: You are looking for locks, why don't use sqlite? If you worried about speed then there Is no solution.

Comment: I suppose I have to redesign my app to avoid dependency on pending Runnables then :(

Comment: You have to assume there are situations you can't have a safe exit. The only callback which is guarantee be excuted is onPause. But still you should be able to handle posible rollbacks.

Answer (score 0):

No other way. LifeCycle methods (onPause/Stop/Destroy) is a standard scenario. There you can clear callbacks for all your runnable objects:

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
        }
    };
handler.postDelayed(runnable, 100);
handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
```

So, it will never called (if it still waiting for run).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I want to make sure that they are not ignored. I mean i want to forcefully run them before exiting. I can probably keep a private list of items by myself and just run all of them. That will do. But I wanted to know if there exists a standard recommended way to handle this properly, than adhoc solutions.

Comment: Manual clean up in onStop/onDestroy the best practice. If process will be killed, no background work will be executed, otherwise onDestroy called.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you must learn how is the activity lifecyle.
http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html

Don't look for a magic trick, just assume what system gives you and choose a proper design.